# Can't make impassable 'wall'

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a basic program in which you can move around a circle with the arrow keys. I'm trying to make it so a certain area cannot be entered by the ball (a blue rectangle), but it's not working.
I'm using Eclipse.

```
package TLOT;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Movement extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
 Timer tm = new Timer(5,this);
 int x = 0, velX = 0;
 int y = 0, velY = 0;

 public Movement()
 {
  tm.start();
  addKeyListener(this);
  setFocusable(true);
  setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  if (x < 0){
   velX = 0;
   x = 0;
  }
  if (x > 633){
   velX = 0;
   x = 533;
  }
  if (y < 0){
   velY = 0;
   y = 0;
  }
  if (y > 410){
   velY = 0;
   y = 310;
  }
  //this is that part thats supposed to make it stop if it hits a certain point.
 if (50 < x && x < 100 && y > 50 && y > 100){
      velX = 0; //700 , 500
      velY = 0;
      }

  x = x + velX;
  y = y + velY;
  repaint();
 }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
  int c = e.getKeyCode();
  if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || c == KeyEvent.VK_A){
   velX = -1;
   velY = 0;
  }
  if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP || c == KeyEvent.VK_W){
   velX = 0;
   velY = -1;
  }
  if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || c == KeyEvent.VK_D){
   velX = 1;
   velY = 0;
  }
  if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || c == KeyEvent.VK_S){
   velX = 0;
   velY = 1;
  }
 }

 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
  velX = 0;
  velY = 0;
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.fillRect(320, 200, 40, 60);
  tm.start();
 }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Movement q = new Movement();
     JFrame jf = new JFrame();
     jf.setTitle("Movement Test");
     jf.setSize(700,500);
     jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     jf.add(q);
     jf.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not working how ?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the problem:

`y > 50 && y > 100`

should of course be

`y > 50 && y < 100`

This is why unit testing, debuggers, desk checking, etc all exist - the programmer's-brain-to-computer interface is buggy and inaccurate ;)

Also, it would be better to check if adding velX and velY will embed you in the wall, not if you already are embedded in the wall. Otherwise you'll just get stuck in it the first time you step in:

`50 < (x+velX) && (x+velX) < 100 && (y+velY) > 50 && (y+velY) < 100`

Even better behaviour would be to make a smaller step such that you exactly end up against the wall. Ways to do this include doing a geometric intersection calculation (circle/rect, circle/circle, rect/rect, poly/poly...) or just trying smaller and smaller steps in a binary search until you get close enough.